# wstring::c_str() contains garbage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, temporary-objects

I have a `std::wstring decode(const char *s)` function.

I use it like this:

```
const char *src = "some string";
const wchar_t *result = decode(src).c_str();
```

I always get garbage in `result[0]`, sometimes in `result[1]` too.

I dont get garbage when I use it in another way:

```
std::wstring res = decode(src);
const wchar_t *result = res.c_str();
```

My `decode` function defined as below, and it does it's job. Only problem is calling code(above).

```
std::wstring decode(const char *s, UINT cp=CP_ACP)
{
    if(s == NULL)
        return std::wstring();
    int length = ::MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, s, -1, NULL, 0 );
    wchar_t *buf = new wchar_t[length];
    ::MultiByteToWideChar(cp, 0, s, -1, buf, length);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
```

I use Visual C++ 2008 SP1 to compile.

Comment: See all the comments about the temporary variable which is this cause of your issue. I'd like to point out that `decode` in your example usage uses one parameter, however `decode` is defined with two parameters. If your intent is to convert from MBCS to widechar you could use the ATL string conversion macro `CA2W` (you can `#include <atlbase.h>` . The macro ATL string macros information  can be found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)

Comment: I have edited code, and provided default arguments, as declared in my header. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const wchar_t *result = decode(src).c_str();
```

The return value of `decode` is a temporary value and is destroyed after the call to `c_str()`. Thus `result` points to freed memory.

So either

- extend the lifetime of the return value (assign it to a local variable, for example)
- copy the result

Comment: I will accept this one. I can also use decode(src).c_str() inside a function call, right?

Comment: Yes. Temporaries are destroyed when the full-expression is finished evaluating. `decode(src).c_str()` as a function argument in a function call is a subexpression to the function call.

Answer (score 5):

> #### 12.2 Temporary objects `[class.temporary]`
>
> 3 When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor (12.1, 12.8), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor (12.4). **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.** This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

So, do not use a temporary after it was destroyed, like in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your specific problems can be found in both the good answers provided. Since the question title was simply `wstring::c_str() contains garbage` I'm going to point out a way to get a result that is correct *without* the `decode` function.

Microsoft added a number of **ATL** conversion macros and classes to convert between wide character (Unicode) and MBCS (Ascii). They are available on VS2008. The supported conversions can be found in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.90).aspx):

> ATL 7.0 introduces several new conversion classes and macros, providing significant improvements over the existing macros. The names of the new string conversion classes and macros take the form:
>   **C**SourceType**2**[C]DestinationType[EX].

[snip]

> SourceType/DestinationType
>
> > **A** = ANSI character string.
> >
> > **W** = Unicode character string.
> >
> > **T** = Generic character string (equivalent to W when _UNICODE is defined, equivalent to A otherwise).
> >
> > **OLE** = OLE character string (equivalent to W).

The `[EX]` is optional and often used if you don't want to specify the size of the default internal buffer that gets used with the macro.

In your case the conversion macro `CA2W` (convert Ascii to Widechar) should do what you want. You only need to `#include <atlbase.h>` to use them. These macros take 2 parameters - the string to be converted and the code page (defaults to CP_ACP if not specified)

In your case you had:

```
std::wstring res = decode(src);
const wchar_t *result = res.c_str();
```

Using the ATL conversion macros you could do it this way:

```
std::wstring res = CA2W(src, CP_ACP);
const wchar_t *result = res.c_str();
```

Since the macros default to Ansi Code Page you can also leave off CP_ACP like this:

```
std::wstring res = CA2W(src);
const wchar_t *result = res.c_str();
```

Regarding the issue with the **temporary objects** the same thing applies to the class returned by these macros. Microsoft even documents this issue with an incorrect usage example in the link provided earlier:

```
// Example 3 
// Incorrect use of conversion macros. 
void ExampleFunction3(LPCWSTR pszW)
{
    // Create a temporary instance of CW2A, 
    // save a pointer to it and then delete 
    // the temportary instance.
    LPCSTR pszA = CW2A(pszW);
    // The pszA in the following line is an invalid pointer, 
    // as the instance of CW2A has gone out of scope.
   ExampleFunctionA(pszA);
}
```